# In $(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty})$ , is the set $\{p(x)\in C[0,1]$, $p(x)$ is a polynomial $:\int_0^1 p(x)dx=1\}$ totally bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, compactness, normed-spaces

Consider the metric space $(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty})$ , in this space , is the set

$\{p(x)\in C[0,1]$, $p(x)$ is a polynomial $:\int_0^1 p(x)dx=1\}$ totally bounded ?

Please help , Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not the unit sphere because we don't take absolute values of $p(x)$. The set is complete I think (being closed), so if it were totally bounded, it would be compact, which I think is easily refuted.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : You are right , the set is not the unit sphere ; but also it is closed in the polynomial subspace not in the whole $C[0,1]$ , it is actually $T^{-1}(\{0\}) \cap \mathcal P[0,1]$ where $T $ is the continuous map $T(f)=\int_0^1 f(t)dt$ from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: Its closure would then be compact. Which it is not, I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : It's closure ... that seems hard to determine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not even bounded. Consider the functions $(n+1)x^n, n = 1,2,\dots $